# Rejected network

Tags: infobip

Can anyone help me with this problem with receiving international message with a local number in the philippines.

Outbound SMS
Rejected - Operator errors
Account not provisioned for global one- or two-way SMS (code 592)
Reason: REJECTED_NETWORK
Hi! This is a test message from Infobip. Have a nice day!
ID:
Number of messages: 1

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting, "Account not provisioned for global one- or two-way SMS (code 592)", means that the mobile operator of the recipient's phone number is not provisioned to receive international SMS messages. This can happen for a few reasons, such as:

1)The recipient's phone plan does not include international SMS messaging.

2)The recipient's phone is not set up to receive international SMS messages.

3)The mobile operator of the recipient's phone is blocking international SMS messages.

To fix this issue, you can try the following:

Check with the recipient's mobile operator to see if they offer international SMS messaging and if their plan includes it.

If the recipient's phone is not set up to receive international SMS messages, they can contact their mobile operator to have it enabled.

If the mobile operator of the recipient's phone is blocking international SMS messages, you can contact them to request that they unblock it.

If you have tried all of these things and the recipient is still not able to receive your international SMS messages, you may need to use a different messaging service that supports international messaging.

Here are some other possible reasons for the error message you are getting:

1)The recipient's phone number is incorrect.

2)The message is too long.

3)The message is formatted incorrectly.

4)The message is being sent from a blocked number.

If you are sure that the recipient's phone number is correct and the message is formatted correctly, you can try shortening the message or sending it from a different phone number.

Comment: How to "use a different phone number" I mean, the "from"